# Distributions of "sequential" binomials

Tags: pr.probability, trees, binomial-distribution, binary-tree

I have come across the following stochastic process which seems very elementary, although I do not know any appropriate terminology for it; I greatly appreciate any suggestions!

Suppose I am given integers $n$ and $k$, with $k\ll n$.  I create a binary tree as follows:

1. Create a root node, with label $n$.
2. While there exists a leaf $u$ whose label $\ell$ is greater than $k$, add two descendants to $u$ whose labels are $X$ and $\ell-X$, where $X$ is a binomial random variable having parameters $1/2$ and $\ell$ respectively.

I am interested in the basic distributional properties of this tree where $n\to\infty$ and $k$ is fixed, such as the depth and the labels of the leaves at termination.  Does this have a name?  I created one output below for $n=100$ and $k=7$:

[image: Sequential binomial sampling with n = 100, k = 7]

Comment: Maybe the downvoter could explain? It looks like there is a typo $X - \ell$ for $\ell - X$, but otherwise it seems like a sensible and maybe interesting question to me.

Comment: Thanks Mark!  Corrected.  I would have appreciated an explanation for the downvote as well.

Comment: Interesting question. I would expect that the depth is approximately normal with mean a multiple of $\log n$ and variance also a multiple of $\log n$. I would expect to be able to compute these constants based on the assumption that the depth is distributed this way, but I have not been able to do so yet.